# Stacking Multiple Rows of Strings in Csv in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code which should stack multiple rows one on top of another in Flutter with the CSV library.

```
exportCsv(List<Drink> drinksFeed, List<Alcohol> alcoholFeed
 ) async {
List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
for (int i = 0; i < drinksFeed.length; i++) {
  List<dynamic> row = List();
  row.add(drinksFeed[i].id);
  row.add(drinksFeed[i].name);
  row.add(drinksFeed[i].description);
  row.add(drinksFeed[i].price);
  rows.add(row);
  setState(() {
    drinksFeed = drinkFeedback;
  });

}
List<List<dynamic>> alcoholRows = List<List<dynamic>>();
for (int i = 0; i < alcoholFeed.length; i++) {
  List<dynamic> row = List();
  row.add(alcoholFeed[i].id);
  row.add(alcoholFeed[i].name);
  row.add(alcoholFeed[i].description);
  row.add(alcoholFeed[i].price);
  alcoholRows.add(row);
  setState(() {
    alcoholFeed = alcoholFeedback;
  });

}


  String drinkCsv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
  String alcoholCsv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(alcoholRows);
  f.writeAsString(drinkCsv);
  f.writeAsString(alcoholCsv);


}
```

}

As you can see, it takes each element from a list and writes it as a string, but for some reason, it isn't stacking rows on top of one another (drinkCsv and alcoholCsv), it just shows the drinksCsv elements in the CSV file. This isn't the full code, because it's too long and I don't think it's relevant to show CSV export, but this should be enough.

**So my question is, is it possible to stack multiple elements one on top of another in 1 csv file (drinkCsv + alcoholCsv in this case).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe awaiting before writing again could solve the problem, also changing the mode to append so it continues writing at the end of the file

```
await f.writeAsString(drinkCsv);
await f.writeAsString(alcoholCsv, mode: FileMode.append);
```

the best solution I can come up is combining the 2 lists before doing the convert (I haven't used that ListToCsvConverter().convert() so I'm not sure how does the string result looks like)

```
String fileCsv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert([...rows, ...alcoholRows]); 

await f.writeAsString(fileCsv);
```

That way maybe the converter do the correct append between the rows when converting to string

Comment: It seems to work better, but still getting some unexpected results, like having the same on the same row as another etc, I suppose this converter wasn't supposed for multiple inputs like this. Is there many some option to have each item separate in the `String drinkCsv =
          const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows)` maybe?

Comment: In this particular case, first item on each list goes into another column on the same row, but only first item, which is weird.

Comment: maybe between the 2 lists convert it should be a \r\n or some way to tell that the second list should start in a new row instead of appending in the same one

Comment: I'll figure it out, your help did solve some issues, so thanks a lot! If I get to the solution, I will write it in the main post.

Comment: try the update, sorry I couldn't help more I don't know how doest the csv package works

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot, I'll try it out. I never worked with it either, so I don't know much about it too.